# How can I create a nested hash as a constant in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, constants, perl-data-structures

I want to do, in Perl, the equivalent of the following Ruby code:

```
class Foo
  MY_CONST = {
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => {
      'innerbar' => 'bleh'
    },
  }

  def some_method
    a = MY_CONST[ 'foo' ]
  end

end

# In some other file which uses Foo...

b = Foo::MY_CONST[ 'baz' ][ 'innerbar' ]
```

That is, I just want to declare a constant, nested hash structure for use both in the class and outside.  How to?

Comment: I already have my Perl class set up (with bless, etc.), so I don't need to be shown how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [Hash::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Hash/Util.html) module to lock and unlock a hash (keys, values, or both).

```
package Foo;
use Hash::Util;

our %MY_CONST = (
    foo => 'bar',
    baz => {
        innerbar => 'bleh',
    }
);

Hash::Util::lock_hash_recurse(%MY_CONST);
```

Then in some other file:

```
use Foo;
my $b = $Foo::MY_CONST{baz}{innerbar};
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael, this is exactly what I need.  I tried to use lock_hashref, but it doesn't seem to be defined for me, but that's okay, I can make do with lock_hash.

Comment: I notice I can accomplish what I need simply with "our", I don't need Hash::Util.  I'm not concerned with other people messing with the hash after the fact, I simply needed to know how to define an accessible constant in Perl.  Your example code showed me.

Comment: So you don't really need a constant? The Hash::Util stuff is the magic that keeps people from changing the hash.

Comment: No, it's a package variable.  Perl does not have "class variables".

Answer (score 11):

You can also do this entirely with builtins:

```
package Foo;
use constant MY_CONST =>
{
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => {
        'innerbar' => 'bleh',
    },
};

sub some_method
{
    # presumably $a is defined somewhere else...
    # or perhaps you mean to dereference a parameter passed in?
    # in that case, use ${$_[0]} = MY_CONST->{foo} and call some_method(\$var);
    $a = MY_CONST->{foo};
}

package Main;  # or any other namespace that isn't Foo...
# ...
my $b = Foo->MY_CONST->{baz}{innerbar};
```

Comment: Thanks, Ether.  I am going to go with this syntax, since it lets me consistently use references everywhere.  I would mark yours as the accepted answer, but it came a bit too late. :)

Comment: Hash::Util::lock_hash_recurse is a fine solution, but I like the built in solution.

Answer (score 4):

See [Readonly](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Readonly):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Foo;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Readonly;

Readonly::Hash our %h => (
    a => { b => 1 }
);

package main;

use strict;
use warnings;

print $Foo::h{a}->{b}, "\n";

$h{a}->{b} = 2;
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> t
1
Modification of a read-only value attempted at C:\Temp\t.pl line 21
```

Comment: Readonly is not installed on the system I'm using, and I'm not at liberty to freely install new modules.  But thanks for your suggestion.  I did come across that when googling.

Comment: @Pistos http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-keep-my-own-module/library-directory%3F

Comment: @Sinan: Thanks, but that doesn't help in my case.  You might be mistaking my circumstances for those of a user on shared hosting or something.  The barriers are not technical, they are social/political/managerial.  :)

Comment: @Pistos: They do trust you with your script, right? You do not need to muck with the system `perl`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guide to hashes in perl. [Hash of Hashes](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~abatko/computers/programming/perl/howto/hash/#create_a_hash_of_hashes__via_references)

Comment: Thanks, thoughI've built nested hashes in general in Perl.  My specific need has to do with using it both within and outside a package/class.